# How to lock scroll for all page?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating image slider, it's contains in big, 100% x 100%, absolute positioning popup div. And I need to block body scroll when slider is active. I tried overflow: hidden for body tag, in js - and it's not working, thereon I tried it in style.css, result was the same.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
```

So how to lock scroll for all page by css resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fixed positioning on your image

```
#myImage
{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Comment: I don't even think about it! The result is better than I had imagined.